# First element repeats instead of copying array

Tags: assembly, emu8086

```
    .model small  

    .stack 64

    .data

    yaz db "Input 5 letter :$"
    s1 db 5dup(0000)
    s2 db 5dup(0000)                                  

    .code   

    MOV AX,@data
    MOV DS,AX
    LEA SI,s1
    LEA BX,s2
    MOV CX,0005

;Keyboard input  

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,yaz 
    INT 21H 

    kaydet: 
    MOV AH,01H
    INT 21H
    MOV [SI],AL 
    INC SI 
    LOOP kaydet 

;Copy

    MOV CX,0005
    LEA SI,s1
    copy:
    MOV AL,[SI]
    MOV [BX],AL
    INC SI
    INC BX
    LOOP copy    

;Output   

    MOV CX,0005   
    LEA BX,s2 
    yazdir:
    MOV AH,02H
    MOV DL,[BX]
    INT 21H
    INC BX
    LOOP yazdir

;End         

    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
    END
```

I am using emu8086 (8086 microprocessor emulator version 4.08).

I am trying to get 5 letter from keyboard and save it to s1. After saving I want to copy s1 to s2. I am trying copy part in other programs; it works correct.

But when i try on this one its only copies the first item of the array. Output is like this "aaaaa" when i input "abcde". Thank you.

Note : Sorry if something wrong on question, this is my first question. Also sorry for my English.

Comment: Make sure `5dup(0000)` actually does what you want. I suggest you write that as `5 dup(0)` (with a space) or even just `db 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` to be sure.

Comment: Thank you, i missed it. It solved when i change it.